# Read data of post method in PHP

Tags: java, php, android

I am requesting to PHP server as below code snippet

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(myString, "UTF-8"); 
httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Now I want to read that xml data into PHP server.

How can I read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xmlstr= file_get_contents('php://input');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
var_dump($xml )
```