# How to prevent double post of data from android to php file

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, post

I have this android app that posts (http post) some data strings to my php file that inserts the data to a mysql table. The problem is, the android app is posting data for about 30 seconds and when the internet connection were accidentally down or interrupted during the posting of data, the user is about to repost the data and so it makes double record on mysql database.

The datasource of my android app is a text file on the device sdcard. after successful posting of data (without interruption), that text file is supposedly deleted.

Comment: one option is to implement a timelimit between two posts

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189712/read-data-of-post-method-in-php/7189758

Comment: jernej: how would timelimit help?
TROODON: yah i'm using something like that to post data. the actual problem is the posting interruption.

Comment: Sorry. Use set_time_limit(0);

Comment: hmm the android app isn't always posting data for 30 sec. it depends on the size of the textfile. is there any other way?

Comment: When you post your date to PHP it can increase ?

Comment: Do you have control of both ends, i.e. can you change code in both the android app as well as the server-side application?

Comment: @VolkerK: yeah i can control both ends. i'm developing both droid and web app.

Comment: @subspider: when i post my data to php, the posted data will be stored in mysql database. my app is reading the text file line by line. each line is a post.

Comment: ok so it's easy :D when you post you get answer then you just delete line :D there for no doble post. i hope i right

Comment: @subspider: oh yah im gonna try that thanks for helping a newbie like me. :)

Comment: @Emkey please quote my comment :D and happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @subspider pointed out. Once the app posted a specific line, it must be deleted so that when internet connection was interrupted, and the user repost data, there will be no double post.

```
                    //check internet connection
                    if( isNetworkAvailable() == true ){
                        //post the data
                        postData( "sessions", sessionnumber, sessionFirstname, sessionIdNumber, sessionLastname, action, username, timestamp);
                        //clear the line/leave the line blank
                        whole_text = whole_text + "\n";
                    }else{
                        //0 means some failed
                        //if internet connection not detected
                        //leave that line as is
                        upload_log_status = 0;
                        whole_text = whole_text + line + "\n";
                    }
```